# Program constantly says missing return statement

Tags: java

My program is supposed to be passed 2 array-lists, arrivals and duration, and should return the number of events that can basically take place without overlap. The last thing I did was add the final else if statement to count the last arrival as an event that could take place. However, my code constantly gives a no return statement error although there is a return statement.

```
class Results {  
public static int maxEvents(List<Integer> arrival,List<Integer> duration) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrival.size(); i++) {
            if (arrival.get(i) + duration.get(i) <= arrival.get(i+1)) {
                counter++;
            } else if (arrival.get(i)==arrival.get(i+1)) {
                counter++;
                i++;
            } else if (i == arrival.size()-1) {
                counter++;
            }
            return counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's going to be returned if `arrival` is empty (i.e. `arrival.size() == 0`).

Comment: `return counter` will be only executed in If statement and else is not handled, so compiler is worried about that scenario, return something in else block as well.

Comment: Return statement should be outside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java compiler requires that all methods with a non-void return type either:

- Return a value (or throw) on all paths
- Definitely don't return a value (e.g. if they contain an infinite loop).

It determines this by looking at the statements in your method to see if they "complete normally". This is a bit of a funny term, but it basically means that execution would move onto the next statement (or the method would finish executing if it is the last statement in the method).

In this case, it looks at the loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arrival.size(); i++) {
        // ...
        return counter;
    }
```

And it finds that:

1. The for loop body completes *abruptly* (it always returns a value)
2. The for loop might be able to complete normally, because `i < arrival.size()` isn't a constant (*).

As such, it looks after the for loop to make sure that all following paths return a value (or throw). But this cannot be the case, because there are no statements after the for loop. As such, a compile-time error results.

The easiest way to satisfy the compiler is to put another return after the for loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arrival.size(); i++) {
        // ...
        return counter;
    }
    return /* some int */;
```

Or make the guard expression constant true (or omit it):

```
    for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
        // ...
        return counter;
    }
```

However, your loop body always returns if entered; so it is basically `if (0 < arrival.size())` rather than a loop. And it would only ever return 0 or 1, because `counter` is incremented at most once.

This is presumably a logical error: the return shouldn't be inside the loop, allowing you to count the number of items in the list which meet the condition:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arrival.size(); i++) {
        // ...
    }
    return counter;
```

---

(*) The compiler doesn't look any deeper than the fact it's not a constant equal to true. For example, `i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE` isn't constant, and thus is considered to allow normal completion, but it is clearly always true.

Answer (score 4):

The return statement which you have written lies within for loop that is incorrect.
please follow below code

```
class Results {  
public static int maxEvents(List<Integer> arrival,List<Integer> duration) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrival.size(); i++) {
            if (arrival.get(i) + duration.get(i) <= arrival.get(i+1)) {
                counter++;
            } else if (arrival.get(i)==arrival.get(i+1)) {
                counter++;
                i++;
            } else if (i == arrival.size()-1) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```